# invert lower triangular matrix

Tags: matrices

I am sorry if the question is simple,am trying to find the quicker method to invert a triangular matrix.
Could you please provide some references where i could refer?
Moreover,is there any known way of obtaining the lower triangular of a Square matrix mathematically?
Thank you!
G

Comment: A very similar question has this answer:
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1232833/how-to-calculate-the-inversion-of-a-triangular-matrix/1611352#1611352

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you start reading about the [LU decomposition.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition)

Comment: Thanks very much,do you think is the fastest way to perform inversion?

Comment: The LU decomposition with partial pivoting is the method used in MATLAB, so it is safe for you to assume it is the best known and tested way available.